# Screen backlight function keys in Arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, asus-laptop, backlight, function-keys

Recently I installed Arch on my ASUS UX31LA. Most of function keys works fine except F5 and F6 (screen backlight keys). I tried to do some research on arch wiki, but couldn't find any page for my model. My DE is Gnome 3 and bootloader is grub.

Q: What should I install or configure to make those keys work?

Answer (score 1):

For me the case on Lenovo X1 Carbon, my video driver is Intel.
To make sure what backlight you have.

`ls /sys/class/backlight/
intel_backlight@`

if you have something else make sure you change it in `Backlight` option below.

`sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-intel-backlight.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection`

Also make sure you install `xf86-video-intel`.

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you receive a key press event.
`xev -event keyboard`

If so, you should be able to map these keys to `light -U 1` and `light -A 1` respectivly.
Light 0.9 (beta)
Copyright (C) 2014 Fredrik Haikarainen

On my system these buttons are named `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp`.

Comment: if `xev` doesn't show any keys, switch to a virtual terminal and run `showkey -s` or `evtest` (you may need to install the `kbd` or `evtest` packages).  if neither of those detect the keys, a special driver or initialization tool may be needed for your laptop's keyboard.

Comment: I receive events from both keys and I installed light. I'm trying to bind those key with xbindkeys, but I cannot bind fn+f5. I checked if I can reveive events from fn key and I can't. However others fn+some key combination works out of the box. I tried bind it also with gnome keyboard settings, but same result.

EDIT: @quixotic I also tested all available devices with evtest, and from none of them I can receive press event from fn key